# ROW_NUMBER in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, row-number

I need fetch the records using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Is there any possibility to achieve this using Google Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Cloud Datastore is a NoSQL database. On the other hand, [ROW_NUMBER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#rank) is a standard SQL numbering function which is supported by Google’s BigQuery service that supports querying using ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datastore is a NoSQL database. On the other hand, [ROW_NUMBER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#rank) is a standard SQL numbering function which is supported by Google’s BigQuery service that supports querying using ANSI SQL.